Copy data from Master workbook with one sheet to another workbook with multiple sheets
I have one master workbook with one sheet having all the data pupulating every 1 min,
data in each row from master work sheet belongs one specific sheet on another workbook,
want to loop through master worksheet from Workbook1 get each row of data
append to the each worksheet from Workbook2.
Ex: Workbook1(Sheet1)             Workbook2(sht1.....100+
    row1         append to         sht1 
    row2         append to         sht2
    row3         append to         sht3

Workbook1 ==> Sheet1
Workbook2==> sht1,sht2,sht3,sht4....upto 100+
have tried this below code it is giving error referencing master sheet cell range and destination sheet cell range
wsCopy.Range(Cells(S, 2), Cells(S, 15)).Copy _
        'wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)

Sub copy_eachrow_from_master()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
  

'EOD_DATA.xlsx is master workbook with Sheet1
'Temp_new.xlsm is having 100's of worksheets.

  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To 180
      Set wsCopy = Workbooks("EOD_DATA.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
      
     Set wsDest = Workbooks("Temp_new.xlsm").Worksheets(i)
     
     lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
             
    wsCopy.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 15)).Copy _
        'wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
        
    
    Next S
    MsgBox "Code done"
    

End Sub


wsCopy.Range(wsCopy.Cells(i, 2), wsCopy.Cells(i, 15)).Copy  All uses of Range/Cells need a worksheet qualifier.   You could also use something like wsCopy.Cells(i, 2).Resize(1, 14).Copy

Copy Each Row to a Different Worksheet
Sub ImportRowsFromMaster()
     
    ' Source (Read From) ('Master')

    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks("EOD_DATA.xlsx")
    Dim sws As Worksheet:: Set sws = swb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Adjust the row. It is unclear whether it is 1, 2 or something else
    ' i.e. the first row usually has headers.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Rows(1).Columns("B:O") ' !!!
    
    ' Destination (Written To) (has 100+ worksheets)
    
    ' If the following is the workbook containing this code,
    ' use 'Set dwb = ThisWorkbook' instead.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("Temp_new.xlsm")
    
    ' It is assumed that there are as many worksheets in the destination
    ' workbook as there are corresponding rows in the source sheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet, dcell As Range, dwsIndex As Long
    
    For dwsIndex = 1 To dwb.Worksheets.Count
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dwsIndex)
        Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        srg.Copy Destination:=dcell
        Set srg = srg.Offset(1) ' next source row range
    Next dwsIndex
    
    MsgBox "Row data imported from Master.", vbInformation

End Sub


From comment above:
Sub copy_eachrow_from_master()

    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wbDest As Workbook, i As Long
      
    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("EOD_DATA.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wbDest = Workbooks("Temp_new.xlsm")

  
    For i = 1 To 180          
        With wbDest.Worksheets(i)
            wsCopy.Cells(i, 2).Resize(1, 14).Copy _   
                Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With     
    Next i
    MsgBox "Code done"

End Sub


Thank you for the reply Williams, am still getting the error in  "Object required"           wsCopy.Cells(i, 2).Resize(1, 14).Copy _
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset (1)

also wanted to check is there any way, I can run this Sub every 5 mnts and terminate this Sub by some condition through Button on the excel.

Copy doesn't like to be 'split' in this way. 'Split' the line anywhere else or e.g. replace the bottom part of the line with Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).

@VBasic2008 - huh I've never seen that before.  Fixed above, thanks.

To schedule a macro to run at a set time or in a loop, you can use Application.OnTime

Thank you all for your responses, I made the changes accordingly, it is working now. posting here in case if it helps anyone else.
Sub copy_eachrow_from_master()
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long


    Dim S As Long
    For S = 2 To 180
        Set wsCopy = Workbooks("EOD_DATA.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  
        Set wsDest = Workbooks("Stocks_Analysis_Data.xlsm").Worksheets(S)
 
        lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
       
        
        wsCopy.Range(wsCopy.Cells(S, 2), wsCopy.Cells(S, 17)).Copy _
            wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)
            
        wsDest.Cells(lDestLastRow, 1).Value = Now

        Next S
   
End If

End Sub

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
